# parallel r, multiple errors

Tags: r, foreach

I am running a foreach loop and am not sure how to interpret some strange behaviour. The functions are tested individually, the loop roughly looks like this:

```
cl<-makeCluster(2, outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl)

outputs <- foreach(k = 1:x, .packages = "various packages") %dopar% {
    do things #contains a for-loop
    return(stuff for output)
}

stopCluster(c1)
```

I get these errors

```
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
In addition: Warning message:
closing unused connection 6 (<-computer:11531)
```

and

```
Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
```

The red dot in rstudio disappears and the console cursor is active again, suggesting it has quit the program.

Now, I know these are pretty non-specific errors, but the really weird thing is that the cluster *still runs* after the errors. The processes spawn, they take up the expected amount of CPU and memory for as long as I would expect the job to take, but I get no return data.

I thought maybe the weird behaviour might be useful to pin down the problem.

Comment: Are you working on a local machine or on a remote cluster?

Comment: Currently on a local machine, testing the code before deploying on a cluster

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error on my local Linux.

Comment: But I didn't give you any of the code? I am using image data so it wouldn't be usable at your end, I was just wondering if anyone could explain the errors and strange behavior

Comment: You say *Using outfile = "" when making the cluster, I get these errors*. `cl<-makeCluster(2, outfile = "")` doesn't throw error for me.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can edit that. Outfile = "" just logs activity, the error occurs with or without using it. I just don't get the "in addition" message.

Comment: Yes, please edit. It is unclear when you get the error.